# when i am typying anything in textField, I want to show button on navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

When i'm start to write anything in textField the search button show in header.

```
-(IBAction)actionCloseKeyboard:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{                      

                     [self adjustLayout:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [countrySelector resignFirstResponder];
                     [searchKeyText resignFirstResponder];
                 }];
//Cancel btn finish
UIButton  *CancelBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[CancelBtn setTitle:CustomLocalizedString(@"CANCEL") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[CancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionCloseKeyboard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
CancelBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
CancelBtn.hidden = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:CancelBtn];

//Search Btn
```

this is my search button which i want to show on navigation bar when I start write anything in text field.

```
UIButton *SearchBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[SearchBtn setTitle:CustomLocalizedString(@"FIND CVS") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[SearchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionFindJobs:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
SearchBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
SearchBtn.hidden = YES;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:SearchBtn];

//Condition Hide and Show

if(CancelBtn == true)
{
    CancelBtn.hidden = NO;
    SearchBtn.hidden = NO;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option it's implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` and in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method check the final number of characters. So if it's greater than 0 show the button, otherwise hide it.

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger finalLenght = textField.text.length - range.length + string.length;
    searchButton.hidden = (finalLenght == 0);

    return YES;
}
```

Also a quick comment, do not use capitals for var names (that's the naming convention). Names starting by capitals are reserved for classes.

Comment: I would probably suggest `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` instead.

Comment: Well `textFieldBeginEditing` and `textFiledDidEndEditing` are called when the UITextField becomes the first responder (get the focus) and stops being it, not when you are actually typing. So let's @muhammad-rehan choose whatever it fits him better

Comment: You're completely right, my mistake. I should probably try to understand the question first! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will work surely,

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
      self.navigationButtonOutlet.hidden=NO;
        return YES;
    }
```

else keep the button hidden as you want

```
  self.navigationButtonOutlet.hidden=YES;
```